# A custom CQ component for Facebook Comments for my webpages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, aem

We have managed to create a custom component for adding facebook comments for our CQ powered web application. We are planning to add this feature to all most every pages in the application.

In the core we have followed this excellent article [add-facebook-comments-to-your-blog](http://socialmouths.com/blog/2012/02/16/add-facebook-comments-to-your-blog/)
But now we are facing a functional challenge. This component will fetch all the comments posted form all the pages to every page. is there a way to filter it on page wise?

To make the question more clear, is it possible to display facebook comments which are posted from the page only?

Please give me some pointers on this.

Thanks and regards,
San

Comment: Set data-href to the url of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the data-href attribute to your include:
*See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings*